# Wrapping lines with long class/attributes names in Python

Tags: python, word-wrap, pep8

I want to wrap the following lines to be PEP compliant and I believe both of them are valid. I have heard some people won't recommend backslashes at all,  Which one is less ugly for you?

## 1

```
    bake_occ_static_pass.compute_behavior = (
        bake_occ_static_pass.original_compute_behavior)
```

## 2

```
    bake_areas_animated_pass.compute_behavior = \
        bake_areas_animated_pass.original_compute_behavior
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 is preferred**. Quoting the word of Gods, aka [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. **Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses.** These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long, multiple `with`-statements
>   cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable.

Even for `import`, the [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) added the parenthesized form, as

```
from Tkinter import (Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text,
    LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END)
```

is prettier than

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Canvas, Text, \
    LEFT, DISABLED, NORMAL, RIDGE, END
```

Comment: Thanks Antti Haapala and @mgilson, Yes I read that, but I couldn't find any examples like mine, In which there is only one element within the parentheses. I thought that was ugly and that's why I suspected it didn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

According to [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

The cases where backslashes are appropriate are only when it would cause syntax problems or really strange line break points to use parenthesis (e.g. `with` and `assert` statements).  e.g.

```
with something('foo') as some_name, \
    something_else('bar') as some_other_name:
```

should be preferred to:

```
with something('foo'
    ) as some_name, something_else(
    'bar') as some_other_name:
```

Answer (score 1):

PEP appears to prefer parentheses over back slashes, and in this situation seeing as how there are no other parentheses in the line to make it more confusing, I would recommend going with the parentheses instead of backslashes.